# Removing "innodb Parameter Not On" Error When Installing Сaсti

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, mariadb, cacti

I am trying to set up a Cacti box to monitor our server environment at work but I am running into a problem that I cannot seem to wrap my head around. The reported error is `"innodb Parameter Not On"`. It is the only error I am getting. The configuration files appear to be in order but I cannot find where to change that particular value.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

MariaDB in 10.10 removed the `innodb` as a system variable. Your version of Cacti still assumes its there and hence `UNSET` as the result. The Cacti upstream have fixed this [bug #5030](https://github.com/Cacti/cacti/issues/5030).

You can assume InnoDB is enabled and ignore this very orange recommendation.